# COSM MQTT subscribe does not receive update status whenever the feed or datastream is updated

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto, cosm

I'm testing the MQTT with COSM.

To publish data, I use below command:

```
$ mosquitto_pub -h api.cosm.com -u <COSM_API_KEY> -t /v2/feeds/96951.csv -m "temp_sensor,21"
```

To subscribe, I use below command:

```
$ mosquitto_sub -h api.cosm.com -u <COSM_API_KEY> -t /v2/feeds/96951/datastreams/temp_sensor.csv
```

I expect in subscribe side, it should get the update status whenever the feed or datastream is updated.
But I only get the current state of the device immediately upon subscription.

Did I miss anything?

Comment: This looks like it could be an issue with Cosm and not a mistake on your end. I'd email Cosm's support.

Answer (score 2):

I think this was fixed on the Cosm end, so the mosquitto_sub example you gave above is working for me now.

Comment: Thanks for let me know that. I just tried again, and I can see the value change in mosquitto_sub side.